# npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY npm ERR! syscall rename while trying to install Expo for react native

Tags: react-native, expo, command-line-interface, zsh

I ran sudo npm i -g expo-cli in terminal.

```
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-dKBr48UN
npm ERR! errno -66
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-dKBr48UN'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/matt/.npm/_logs/2021-03-22T18_33_07_275Z-debug.log
```

Getting this error above and cant figure out how to install expo correctly. Anyone know how to resolve this?

Also, keep getting ZSH permissions denied and the expo command does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
navigating to '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/'
delete it
Run sudo npm install --global expo-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

If on Mac or unix system, you can fix it by..

remove permissions:
sudo -s

go to the directory it tells you in the error, like:

cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli

then remove the file:
rm -r /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli

then
try installing it again.

npm install -g expo-cli

Answer (score 0):

If on Linux Distribution or Mac System, you can fix it by..

remove permissions: **sudo -s**

go to the directory it tells you in the error, like:

**cd /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli**

then remove the file: **rm -r /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli**

then try installing it again.

**sudo npm install -g expo-cli**